# Solving integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(2\pi-i2\pi t) f}}{(3+i2\pi f)^2}df$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

If Fourier transform of $h(t)$ is $H(f)=\dfrac{2}{(3+i2\pi f)^2}$ and Fourier transform of $x(t)$ is $X(f)=e^{-2\pi f}$, then determine the convolution of $h(t)*x(t)$.

---

From the theorem
$$f(t)*g(t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[F(\omega)G(\omega)]$$
I got
$$\begin{align}h(t)*x(t)&=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\dfrac{2e^{-2\pi f}}{(3+i2\pi f)^2}\right]\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2e^{-2\pi f}}{(3+i2\pi f)^2}\cdot e^{i2\pi ft}df\\&=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-(2\pi-i2\pi t) f}}{(3+i2\pi f)^2}df\end{align}$$
but I'm stuck with the latter integral. Help is needed. Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll be able to do this via contour integration with a semicircular contour in the upper plane? You just have one order 2 pole.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $e^{-2\pi|f|}$ and not $e^{-2\pi f}$?

Comment: There's a slight typo in your post OP, your last line is off by a negative factor. I'll write a solution up in a little bit for you..currently on my phone.